# Scala multidimensional array equivalent of np.ndarray.shape?

Tags: scala

Is there a pithy way to get the shape of a multidimensional array in Scala? I'm thinking of something equivalent to the following using Numpy in Python:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a
>> array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
a.shape
>> (2, 3)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem so much a question about arrays, but rather a question about an adequate replacement for `np.array(...)`. If you don't use any libraries, then you can't do much with arrays anyway, or at least it's going to be much less comfortable than using numpy. Shouldn't you look out for a library that works with multidimensional tensors, [ND4J](https://nd4j.org/scala) for example?

Comment: Good point. It's not really an apples-to-apples comparison to ask for a native Scala implementation of a third party Python library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure, that all the inner Arrays are of the same size, you can do:

```
scala> val aaa = Array ( Array (1,2,3), Array (4,5,6))                        
aaa: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))

scala> val aaaShape = (aaa.size, aaa(0).size)
aaaShape: (Int, Int) = (2,3)
```

but an Array of Arrays doesn't guarantee, that all inner Arrays are of the same size.

A method like a.shape seems over engineering, but you may write it yourself easily and then implement a check for even size of each subarray, if appropriate.